# Word (365): Comments: "Resolve" is always disabled

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-365

[image: screenshot of problem]

"Resolve" is disabled in this document for all comments. Even if I insert a new comment, I can't resolve it.

Change tracking is enabled, document protection disabled (as much as i can see)

Comment: Does this issue occur with all Word documents? Please refer to Doug Robbins's reply in [Cannot Mark Comments as Resolved ("Resolved" button grayed out)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/cannot-mark-comments-as-resolved-resolved-button/019ce162-0e98-4ba8-a667-cbbbe61c4c8e).

Comment: Thanks! "Compatibility Mode" was the problem. (If you like to post that as answer, I can accept it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, thanks peterchen very much.

---

Please check if there is "Compatibility Mode" shown next the file's name at the top of the Word app.

If so, please backup the file fist, then upgrade the document to the newest file format via going to File > Info, use **Convert**  function.

[image]

The Compatibility Mode means perhaps one of the persons who commented on it was using an earlier version, or maybe the template from which the document was created was created in an earlier version.