# 'Resolve comment' button in word not showing

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

I am working on a shared document in Word (part of Microsoft 365 for Enterprise), currently with a large number of comments, but am unable to mark comments as resolved.

This is perhaps similar to the issue of the [resolve comment button being greyed out](https://superuser.com/questions/1589464/word-365-comments-resolve-is-always-disabled), except that I can't see the 'resolve' button at all.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? Might it be related to working on a shared document? Or caused by the large number of comments (currently 137) in the document?

I have tried starting a new document, and the resolve comments button appears as normal (see images below), so it is clearly something the matter with this particular document.

How the button normally appears:
[image: How the button normally appears]

How the menu appears in my current document:
[image: How the menu appears in my current document]

Comment: Is it possible that these comments were created using the legacy Comments feature whereas you're using the [Modern Comments](https://insider.microsoft365.com/en-us/blog/modern-commenting-in-word) feature? [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-msoffice_unknown-mso_subother/modern-comments-control-screenshots-for-windows/857ac31e-33f7-4aeb-9fc3-d2224d3e2d37)

Comment: The 'enable modern comments' box is checked, so I think they're all modern comments. I've also just tried adding a new comment (using the 'new comment' button in the review tab on the ribbon), but the same problem occurs.

Comment: Your [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1589464/word-365-comments-resolve-is-always-disabled) talks about compatibility mode. Are you using this mode for this document? Is your document `.doc` or `.docx` and when was it created?

Comment: Ah sorry. It's not saying compatibility mode, and I made the file within the last fortnight

Comment: Only thing to point out is it's based on a template given to me by my employer, so I'm not sure when this was first created

Answer (score 1):

I understand that documents created using your employer's template
don't have the "Resolve thread" option, but documents you create
with your Normal template do have it.

A possible explanation might be that this template and its comments
were created using an older Word version that used the legacy
Comments feature, whereas you're now using the
[Modern Comments](https://insider.microsoft365.com/en-us/blog/modern-commenting-in-word)
feature.

If this explanation is correct, you will need to ask your employer
to recreate his template using a more modern Word version
with Modern Comments enabled.

For more information see for example
[Modern Comments control](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-msoffice_unknown-mso_subother/modern-comments-control-screenshots-for-windows/857ac31e-33f7-4aeb-9fc3-d2224d3e2d37).